# cmd windows not showing output

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm having an issue where my cmd windows is just blank when executed from code. I've searched here and there for some solutions. And tried a few different things myself.

Running it with a normal .bat file works just fine.. But just not from my C# application.

Note: the **ffmpeg** is being run perfectly, but just not showing anything in the cmd window when executed from code.

image at the bottom.
I'll update this if I find a solution.. Unless you guys do it first ;)

Code:

```
      private async void RunFfmpeg()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
        String destFolder = null;
        String sourceFolder = null;
        int listCount = 0;

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            destFolder = textDest.Text;
            sourceFolder = textSource.Text;
            listCount = listFiles.Items.Count;
        });



        foreach (FileInfo fileC in listFiles.Items)
        {
            //Changing old extension to mp4
            string oldFileName = fileC.ToString();
            string newFileName = null;

            string[] extension = oldFileName.Split('.');

            newFileName = extension[0] + ".mp4";

            string newDir = destFolder + "\\" + extension[0];
            DirectoryInfo createDir = new DirectoryInfo(newDir);

            if (!createDir.Exists)
            {
                createDir.Create();
            }

            //Gathering folders and all I need...
            string output = "\"" + destFolder + "\\" + extension[0] + "\\" + newFileName + "\"";
            string input = "\"" + sourceFolder + "\\" + oldFileName + "\"";

                var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    //Arguments = $"-i {input} {output}",
                    Arguments = $"/c ffmpeg -i {input}" + " -c:a copy -c:v copy " + $"{output}",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                    WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
                };
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo = startInfo;
                p.OutputDataReceived += P_OutputDataReceived;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is where I read the output:

```
        private void P_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            //string cmdBox = cmdOutput.Text;
            //cmdOutput.AppendText(cmdBox);
            //cmdOutput.Clear();
            cmdOutput.AppendText(e.Data);
        });
    }
```

[image: Images showing blank cmd]

Comment: Where are you writing to standard output? It looks like you are doing a copying to a file.  Did you check the output file to see the time stamp and size?

Comment: @jdweng I'm using ffmpeg to convert a file/files. And it has it's own output when you run it. Like showing how many frames and time it has used. So when I run ffmpeg.exe from a bat file, it will open a cmd Windows with the updating output. Im using outputdatarecieved. But that is not my current issue... The problem is that the cmd window that is being opened from my application is just a black blank page.. Not showing the ffmpeg output.

Comment: Is the output going to Standard Output or Standard Error?

Comment: @jdweng standard output. But I updtated my previous reply..

Comment: Try adding a flush which will take current stream and make sure it gets sent to command window.

Comment: @jdweng I'll try that when I'm at my computer again. I'll update you on this.

Comment: It could be that ffmpeg detects the terminal type, and only outputs to a terminal, and not to a pipe