# VirtualEnv not showing in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, virtualenv

My problem is preety much the same as [this guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55245315/cmd-windows-not-showing-output).

I can activate my virtual environment in cmd but it's name won't show on the prompt to let me know it's active. This worries me as I might mess up my virtual environment's packages or my actual env's packages.
This problem started happening right after I ran:
`pip install --upgrade virtualenv` and upgraded my virtualenv's version.

I'd like to know how to make the name start showing up on windows cmd.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the virtualenv version. It's because of the virtualenv version. I had the same problem. So, what solved for me was to uninstall the current version and install an older version, for example, 16.7.9.

**pip install virtualenv==16.7.9**